# Setting a transparent background to an image

Tags: android

I'm getting an image URL from JSON, I set it in `ImageView` by using the picasso library.

However, I'm facing one problem: the image I am getting from the URL does not have a transparent background.

How do I make it transparent and then set it to `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

LOL,
For this,

Your image needs to be transparent.

You can only make background of ImageView transparent not image in Android.